# Validate property based on another property keys

Tags: typescript

I would like to improve the type-checking of the following object:

```js
interface Config {
    fields: Record<string, unknown>;
    table: { id: string }[];
}

const config: Config = {
    fields: {
        id: {}
    },
    table: [
        { id: 'id' },
        { id: 'name' },
    ]
};
```

The part I'm struggling with is that I want to **type-check** that the `table` object `id` should match a key in `fields`. If `table > id` is not present in `fields` keys, then it should error. So:

- `{ id: 'id' }` is OK, since `id` key exists in `fields`
- `{ id: 'name' }` should error, `name` key doesn't exist in `fields`

Is this possible? Plan B is to do this check at runtime.

Comment: From what I can tell what you are describing isn't type checking, its value comparison and it will have to be done at runtime.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this with a `type` alone, but a generic type in combination with a function could validate this on compile time. Would that be ok for you?

Comment: I assume that it would be generic over `fields`, with a concrete type where all `fields` keys are known? Uhmm... or to simplify I suppose I could use a const array of field ids and use that as the generic. What was your idea?

Comment: something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAyD4m)? If this does fit your use case, I could write an answer

Comment: That's actually neat, in my case I want create a mapper function from a new config format to an older one, so this works for my use case.

Comment: what kind of value the field id get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible (yet) to create a standalone `type` which can do validation like that. But generic `type`s are powerful enough to achieve this. Generic types for validation are best used in combination with a function.

```
function useConfig<F>(config: { fields: F, table: { id: keyof F }[]}) {}
```

In this function we have the generic type `F` which holds information about the object we pass with the `fields` property. We can then use `keyof F` inside `table`.

Some tests to validate the result:

```
useConfig({
    fields: {
        id: {}
    },
    table: [
        { id: 'id' }
    ]
})
// works

useConfig({
    fields: {
        id: {}
    },
    table: [
        { id: 'id' },
        { id: 'name' }
    ]
})
// error

useConfig({
    fields: {
        id: {},
        name: {}
    },
    table: [
        { id: 'id' },
        { id: 'name' }
    ]
})
// works
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAyD4m)

Comment: Thanks! This is going to be super handy.

Comment: one more recommendation from my side would be to not use an object for the `fields`. Instead use an array with the properties as `string`s so you don't have empty `{}` for no good reason :) . See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mp9bXW)

Comment: Oh, I was using an empty object to not complicate the example, but the idea is that I'll have `fields` definitions (e.g. `label`, `type`, etc.) and then I'll have, for example,`table` & `form` properties that define which of these fields will show on the tables and forms (hence an ordered array). For that I need to enforce that the `id` is actually a valid field. Then on `table/form` I might have extra props that make sense in that context. So, TLDR, objects are fine. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
type fieldsType = {id:any}
const config:{fields:fieldsType, table:{[k:string]:keyof fieldsType}[]} = {
    fields: {
        id: {},
    },
    table: [
        { id: 'id' },
        { id: 'name' },
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work, although I don't like the explicit list of fields on the generic… it would be more convenient if there was some kind of type-magic for this. ^_^U

```js
interface Config<T extends string> {
    fields: {
        [P in T]: unknown
    };
    table: { id: T }[];
}

const config: Config<'id' | 'title'> = {
    fields: {
        id: {},
        title: {},
    },
    table: [
        { id: 'id' },
        { id: 'name' }, // <== this errors
    ]
};
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2AcwDwAqyEAHpCACYDOyVYUoOAfMgN4BQyXy2EANtQBcbTtzEBtAArJQyAgF1hAVxABrEOgDuIUVwC+Abl3IwcAEZ8Iw1jIrCie8fKN727BJjrIPWXMIy++ADkwBRByAA+yEFgwGCWQSwAvCJivAJU1sZiodZ6ADTZ3LHxVmwFxhViphZl4kVcNrnRoeFV3PLshkA).